# Is my comparison of squared loss, absolute loss, and huber loss correct?

Tags: loss-functions

According to the definitions of the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss), squared loss ($\sum(y^{(i)}-\hat y^{(i)})^2$), and absolute loss ($\sum|y^{(i)}-\hat y^{(i)}|$), I have the following interpretation. Is there anything wrong?
[image]
Here, by *robust to outliers* I mean the samples that are too far from the best linear estimation have a low effect on the estimation. On the other hand, by *insensitive to noise* I mean the deviations of the samples that are very close to the best linear function have a low effect on the estimation.

Note1: By *robust to outlier* and *insensitive to noise*, I just mean robust or insensitive, *compared to* other methods.

Note2: Why I think *absolute loss* is not insensitive to noise compared to others? Because it has higher values for low losses than two other methods.

Comment: 1) Huber loss is not differentiable at the hinges, 2) Why do you think absolute loss is sensitive to noise but the other two are not?

Comment: @jbowman 1) Are you sure? I know that it is differentiable even at the hinges, 2) The question is edited to explain it. Thank you.

Comment: 1) You are correct, I was thinking of the influence function instead of the loss function for some reason.  Not enough coffee yet, I suppose.  2)  Note that rescaling your variables can always make $x^2 < |x|$ over any range of the original variable you want.  So having higher values for low losses doesn't mean much (in this context), because multiplying everything by, for example, $1e6$ may ensure there are NO "low losses", i.e., losses $< 1$.

Comment: @jbowman 1) OK:), 2) Exactly because of this, i.e., $x^2<|x|$ I think absolute loss is more sensitive to the noise (by rescaling we just determine our threshold for noise). In fact, I am seeking for a reason that why the Huber loss uses the squared loss for small values, and till now, I have not find anything else than the squared loss is less sensitive to small losses.

Comment: I believe that what Hossein refers to as "sensitivity to noise" would be called "local shift sensitivity" in the statistical robustness literature; it relates to the supremum of the absolute value of the derivative of the influence function.